# Проблемы с кодом для 1С: Предприятие

Tags: 1с, форма

Нужна помощь с кодом для 1С: Предприятие. На форме "ФормаЭлемента" справочника "Номенклатура" есть табличная часть "Характеристики". Необходимо сделать функциональность, которая позволит при открытии формы добавить строку в таблицу программно.

Код:
&НаСервере
Процедура ПриСозданииНаСервере(Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка)
Если Характеристики.Отбор.Элементы.Количество() > 0 Тогда
Характеристики.Отбор.Элементы[0].ПравоеЗначение = Объект.Ссылка;
Иначе
// Функциональность с добавлением строки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры;

Comment: Не понятно, когда именно требуется добавлять строку в ТЧ